# Error Initializing app: there was an error with the spawned command: npminstall

Tags: ionic2

Steps to reproduce:
1. Following initial npm install -g cordova ionic and circumventing proxy issues I type the following

ionic start test-app blank
.../ionic-app-base.../master.zip 
.../ionic-start-blank.../master.zip

both download 100%

Installing npm packages

Error with start undefined

Error Initializing app: there was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
Caught exception:
  undefined
Post the output of ionic info below please

Error Initializing app: there was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
Caught exception:
undefined

Comment: I'm also having this issue, can anybody help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated npm with latest version 6.9.5. And it works fine.